# Passing Array of dict as parameter to ros launch

Tags: python, parameters, ros, args

I want to pass an array of dict as parameter to launch file and retrieve these arrays at the node. How can I achieve this. Not finding any example or pseudo-code regarding this. Newbie ros user.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you should use [rosparams](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam). This will let you pass in data in a YAML format. If loading the params in a python node they will come in as a `dict`, if c++ they will come in as a `std::map`.

For example, if you wanted it to behave like:

`my_dict = {key1: {iKey1: val1, iKey2: val2}, key2: [1,2,3], key3: something_else}`

your launch file would look like this:

```
<rosparam>
    my_dict:
        key1:
            iKey1: val1
            iKey2: val2
        key2: [1,2,3]
        key3: something_else
</rosparam>
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion , anyway to dynamically append my_dict? I need to append the user inputs from GUI into this dict and pass this info to the node on launch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the node being launched?

Comment: with launch file

Comment: without know more about the GUI I cannot say. It will either have to construct the YAML directly or make use of the [rosparam API](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server) setting the params directly.